# What are the names of these aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I need help to identify a group of planes, can someone help me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: NC248V was registered as a Fairchild KR-135 (http://www.airhistory.org.uk/gy/reg_N32.html) but that doesnt look right.

Comment: @Jamiec Looks like the model builder ran out of "V" decals, so he flipped an "A" upside down. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The top image is a [Bellanca Skyrocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellanca_31-40).

[image: Bellanca Skyrocket]

The second image looks like the Fairchild FC-1, one was built as a prototype, followed by the [FC-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_FC-2) which was powered by a radial engine.

[image: Fairchild FC-1]

Not sure about the last, found a few similar but nothing exact.

Comment: The top one looks different from the Bellanca Skyrocket picture: different angle of vertical tail, different rudder, different engine cowling shape.

Comment: @Koyovis there are a few different models of the Skyrocket, the cowling and tail do have differences

Comment: [Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/Bellanca_XRE-3_Skyrocket_USMC_c1933.jpeg) is a better picture of an XRE-3 Skyrocket (civilian name CH-400). The tail and the wing struts match a lot better. The one in the question sports a NACA cowling and indicates a late series model.